# Non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem: universal TM overhead

Tags: time-complexity

I am currently reading the book of Arora and Barak on computational complexity.
In the third chapter (p69-70), two classic theorems regarding time complexity hierarchies are introduced:

$\left[f(n)\log(f(n)) = \mathcal{o}(g(n))\right] \Rightarrow \left[DTIME(f(n) \subset DTIME(g(n))\right]$
$\left[f(n+1) = \mathcal{o}(g(n))\right] \Rightarrow \left[NTIME(f(n) \subset NTIME(g(n))\right]$

The proofs that are given for these theorems make use of (lazy) diagonalization of a universal TM that flips the answer.  This presumes we can simulate a TM $M$ that runs in $f(n)$ time using a universal TM $U$ that runs in $g(n)$.  For the deterministic case, this is possible, as the overhead of the universal TM is logarithmic (so for large enough $n$, we have $T(n) = f(n)$ and $U(n) = g(n) > f(n)\log(n)$).  For the non-deterministic part however, the $\log$ factor is dropped.  Could someone explain to me why the $\log$ factor isn't needed in this case?

The proofs of the book don't really help, as they only prove the theorem for the specific case in which $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = n^{1.5}$.

Comment: The proof for non-deterministic case is quite different from deterministic case. I am guessing your problem is with the part that says "simulate $M_i$ on input 1^{n+1} using nondeterminism in $n^{1.1}$ time" and similarly in the following line. Right?

Comment: ps: you might be interested in this post: [A New Proof of the Nondeterministic Time Hierarchy](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2011/04/new-proof-of-nondeterministic-time.html)

Comment: ps: if you want to have a look at the original paper that proved the stronger result the paper is here: [Seiferas, Fischer, Meyer, "Separating Nondeterministic Time Complexity Classes", 1978](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/710/seiferas.pdf) It is quite more complicated than the simpler polynomial case.